# Comparing the performance of two classifiers using cross-validation

Tags: estimation, t-test, model-selection

Consider the following excerpt (paraphrased, see sec. 4.6.3 for original wording) from [Introduction to Data Mining](https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/ch4.pdf) (*free* chapter) by Pang-Ning Tan, Michael Steinbach, and Vipin Kumar.

> Suppose we use $k$-fold cross validation to compare the performance of two classifiers by splitting the data into $k$ partitions, and then performing the following procedure for $k$ times:
>
> 1. Train two models, $M_{1 j}$ and $M_{2 j}$ on the $j$-th fold (consisting of $k - 1$ partitions); then
> 2. Measure their error rates and denote them as $e_{1 j}$ and $e_{2 j}$ respectively.
>
> Now, in order to check if the difference $d = e_{1} - e_{2}$ is statistically significant, we can do a $t$-test.  We estimate the variance by
>   $$
> \begin{equation}
> \hat{\sigma}_{d}^2 = \frac{\sum\nolimits_{j = 1}^{k} (d_j - \bar{d})^2}{k (k - 1)}\text{.}
> \end{equation}
> $$

It is the variance estimate that I do not understand.  More specifically, why do we divide by $k (k - 1)$?  As far as I'm aware, all we're doing is a [paired $t$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test#Dependent_t-test_for_paired_samples) -- why don't we divide just by $k - 1$ when estimating the variance?

Comment: How are the error rates defined?

Comment: @Greenparker: They are defined as the number of wrongly classified observations.

Comment: Not 100% sure, and I don't really agree with the method; but reading the full text, the key could be "if k is sufficiently large, assume normality in dj". The variance for the formula in your post is $\hat{\sigma}_{d}^2$, however the variance in the text is $\hat{\sigma}_{d^{cv}}^2$, which is actually $\hat{\sigma}_{d}^2/(k-1)$ Hope it helps.